# Operation failed: No projects supported by NuGet in the solution - in Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have a Node.js Visual Studio 2017 Community project. When I right-click the solution in the solution explorer and select *Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...* I get this popup:

[image: Operation failed: No projects supported by NuGet in the solution]

After that, the context menu option is disabled:

[image: Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... (disabled)]

The solution contains single Node.js project created in aforementioned Visual Studio version.

So I suppose I need to add NuGet support to the project somehow?

Comment: NuGet is for DLL's NPM is for JavaScript modules.

Comment: I don't think nuget support node.js project, npm is the right solution for package management for node.js project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet is a package manager for .Net projects, it allows you to install third-party libraries for you to use them in your .Net project.

As you're using Node.JS you should use NPM instead, which is the Node Package Manager.

More info on the differences can be found on [this blog entry](https://www.google.es/amp/s/jessedotnet.com/2016/01/07/nuget-vs-npm-vs-bower/amp/)

Info about NPM [here](https://www.npmjs.com)